# Raspberry Pi 3 - One pin sending different voltage (4.25 instead of 3.3)

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, iot, gpio

I am working with the SainSmart 16-Channel Relay board and everything is working fine except for one pin is sending a different voltage. This is causing the relay to shutoff after a few seconds. All the pins show 3.3v except for pin 4 that is showing  4.25v when I test the terminal with my multi-meter. I have added a 1k resister inline with the GPIO pin because the board is designed for Arduino and not the Raspberry Pi. The resister has corrected the voltage difference issue because 15 other relays work fine. Also I am reading this voltage issue before the 1k resistor so it should be effecting this.

I have changed out the Raspberry Pi board and the relay board with another thinking that was the issue and am receiving the exact same voltage. Any ideas as to what the issue could be would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using to test pins 2-8.

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class Create_Button:
    def __init__(self,pin):
        self.pin = pin
        GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(self.pin, GPIO.HIGH)

        self.b = Button(text="Pin %s" % self.pin + " - Turn Relay On", command=self.toggle)
        self.b.pack()

    def toggle(self):
        print(self.pin)
        if GPIO.input(self.pin):
            GPIO.output(self.pin, GPIO.LOW)
            self.b.config(text="Pin %s" % self.pin + " - Turn Relay On")
        else:
            GPIO.output(self.pin, GPIO.HIGH)
            self.b.config(text="Pin %s" % self.pin + " - Turn Relay Off")

root = Tk()
root.title("Toggler")    

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(FALSE)

for pin_count in range(2,9+1):
    button = Create_Button(pin_count)

quitButton = Button(root, text="Quit", command=exit)
quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```